# anyone calculate the tree creating algorithm's running time in worst case?

Tags: algorithm, tree

I designed an algorithm to generate complete binary tree. I know this algorithm is sucks and also have better solution but I just wonder if the code below will take O(n), O(n*n!) or O(nlogn).

I used a linkedlist.

```
    public LinkedData GetDataByIndex(LinkedData list, int index)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            if (list.Next == null)
                return null;
            list = list.Next;
        }
        return list;
    }

    public TreeNode CreateTree(TreeNode node, LinkedData list, int index)
    {
        if (index == 0) //root
        {
            node = new TreeNode();
            node.Value = list.Value;
        }
        //Left
        int leftIndex = index*2 + 1;
        LinkedData data = GetDataByIndex(list, leftIndex);
        if (data != null)
        {
            node.Left=new TreeNode();
            node.Left.Value = data.Value;
            CreateTree(node.Left, list, leftIndex);
        }

        //Right
        int rightIndex = index*2 + 2;
        data = GetDataByIndex(list, rightIndex);
        if (data != null)
        {
            node.Right=new TreeNode();
            node.Right.Value = data.Value;
            CreateTree(node.Right, list, rightIndex);
        }

        return node;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your algorithm is dominated by `GetDataByIndex` which is called for every item in your list. So, `GetDataByIndex` is called `2n` times and itself has a runtime of `O(n)`. Therefore I would say this is a `O(n^2)` algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to access the list of values by index, why don't you copy it into an ArrayList so that accessing items by position is O(1).  That would make the whole tree building algorithm O(N), since CreateTree is called once for each node, and perform O(1) work in each call.